# Exponential likelihood

Tags: survival, inference, modeling

I have a random variable $T$ that represents time to failure.

I can make a simple model where $T$ is exponentially distributed iid for some rate $\lambda$. We can estimate $\lambda$ with e.g. failure times or alive times and end up with an Exponential/Gamma posterior (assuming exponential or a uniform prior). Based on the likelihood function and the iid assumption, the order of things doesn't matter. The mean estimate for time to failure amounts to roughly the total time elapsed divided by the failure count. Sensible and simple.

What if I wanted to consider something where the current state's likelihood changes based on its previous state history? That is, the order of things matter. E.g. many failures means more failures or "looping" behaviour where things go between failure/success, etc. What kind of models can I consider?

Comment: Perhaps an [autoregressive conditional duration model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_duration) might be relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options. Some models with available implementations include:

- multistate models that allow your rate to depend on the state
- exponential regression models that allow rates to be different based on known information about each unit
- frailty models that allow different rates for different units
- semi-Markov models (ordinary survival models) that allow the rate to depend on the time since the last failure

I will also note that it's sometimes hard to distinguish some conceptually different models based on data. For example, a model that says your rate of events increases if you've had an event recently is not easily distinguishable from a model that says your rate is constant over time but different people have different rates. (I go into more detail [here](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2024/01/12/recurrent-events-increased-susceptibility-or-latent-risk/))